# How to test the removal of images using Ajax in Rspec

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, testing, rspec

I have an images on the page, which I removed via Ajax.

I want to test deleting images.

Controller:

```
def destroy

    current_image = Image.find(params[:id])
    current_car = current_image.car

    Image.delete_image_file(params[:id])    
    flash[:notice] = t('activerecord.errors.controllers.message.attributes.image.image_destroy_success')

    @images = current_car.images.order("order_id")

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to images_path(:car_id => params[:id]) }
      format.js
    end

  end
```

File destroy.js.erb - Refreshing view and showing flash message

```
$('#image_list').html("<%= escape_javascript(render('list')) %>")
$('#div_flash_box').html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'layouts/flash', :locals => { :flash => flash }).html_safe %>")
```

View of images: _list.html.erb

```
<ul id="ul_images" data-update-url="<%= sort_images_url %>">  
  <% @images.each do |image| %>
    <%= content_tag_for :li, image, :class => 'ui-state-default' do %>     
     <%= link_to image_tag("#{RAILS_CAR_VIEW_IMAGES}" + "#{image.name}/" + image.image_thumb_file), "#{RAILS_CAR_VIEW_IMAGES}" + "#{image.name}/" + image.image_file, :class => 'group1' %>
     <div class="div-images-delete"><%= link_to t('views.buttons.delete'), image, :method => :delete, :remote => true, :confirm => t('views.forms.confirm') %></div>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

My tests in Rspec

```
it "should delete an image using Ajax" do
  lambda do
    xhr :delete, :destroy, :id => @image.id
    response.should be_success
  end.should change(Image, :count).by(-1)  
end



it "should destroy image" do
   xhr :delete, :destroy, :format => "html"
   flash[:notice].should == I18n.t('activerecord.errors.controllers.message.attributes.image.image_destroy_success')
end
```

Cars and Images are in relationships

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :car,
   :foreign_key => "car_id"

class Car < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :images
```

Failures:

1) ImagesController for signed-in users should delete an image using Ajax
     Failure/Error: xhr :delete, :destroy, :id => @image.id
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `images' for nil:NilClass
     # ./app/controllers/images_controller.rb:32:in`destroy'
     # ./spec/controllers/images_controller_spec.rb:36:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/controllers/images_controller_spec.rb:35:in`block (3 levels) in '

2) ImagesController for signed-in users should destroy image
     Failure/Error: xhr :delete, :destroy, :format => "html"
     ActionController::RoutingError:
       No route matches {:format=>"html", :controller=>"images", :action=>"destroy"}
     # ./spec/controllers/images_controller_spec.rb:42:in `block (3 levels) in '

What's wrong?

Comment: What kind of test are you trying to create? Controller or integration? Also, what error are you getting?

Comment: I want to check the controller, but what should I test?

Comment: That's fine. I saw xhr and I though you were testing an ajax view.

Answer (score 1):

For the first error, I believe that the `current_car` object has not been set in the test environment. That's why there is a NilClass error when `.images` is called.

Answer (score 1):

The first error is because the image you're trying to delete doesn't have an associated car. This sounds like you forgot to create a car when creating the data for this test.

The other error is because you missed the `id` parameter in the test:

```
xhr :delete, :destroy, :format => "html"
```

should be

```
xhr :delete, :destroy, :id => @image.id, :format => "html"
```

Comment: Thank you, but...    Failure/Error: xhr :delete, :destroy, :id => @image.id, :format => "html"
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `images' for nil:NilClass

Comment: @user1466717 That's the same error you're getting at the first test, and it's because the test database is not well populated. The image doesn't have an associated car.